# on button click detection

Tags: android

I am working on this android project which calculates taxi-fares. It has a button `calculate`, and a menu option `night-mode`. This `calculate` method determines the distance between two points, and also the taxi fare that goes with it.

`night-mode` calculates the taxi-fare as per the different rates we have here work the night-cab. The basic requirement for `night-mode` is that it can only operate if and only if the `calculate` goes into the onClick event/ if the method is executed.

In my menu option ... how can i check that the button was really clicked/ or the onClick event was triggered ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a status variable which is changed after OnClick from your calculate-method and check if your variable has a specific value when nightmode is clicked (both as button version)

example:

```
    int integer=0;

    public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v == calculate){
                    if (integer == 0)
                            integer =1; //this makes your integer variable 1 if calculate is pressed the first time

                    else if (integer == 1)
                            integer=0;//this makes your integer variable 0 if calculate is pressed the second time(at the end of the drive)
    //do calculate things
    }
    else if (v == nightmode){
            if(integer == 1){
            //do nightmode things
            }
            else{}
    }
```